# Looking for an app to create icon size art

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics

Can I ask a for a recommendation for an app.  I am looking for a user friendly app that I can use to make, resize, and save in jpeg and png format, icon size art.  Being new to Apple I have no idea.  Free would be good too.  Many thanks.

Comment: by Make? you mean what?

Comment: Sorry yea, by make I intend, produce.

Comment: this tutorial might help http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Creating_Icons/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get [GIMP](http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html)! It's LGPLv3+ und GPLv3+ licensed.

> GIMP is a multi-platform photo manipulation tool. GIMP is an acronym for GNU Image Manipulation Program. The GIMP is suitable for a variety of image manipulation tasks, including photo retouching, image composition, and image construction.
>
> GIMP has many capabilities. It can be used as a simple paint program, an expert quality photo retouching program, an online batch processing system, a mass production image renderer, an image format converter, etc.
>
> GIMP is expandable and extensible. It is designed to be augmented with plug-ins and extensions to do just about anything. The advanced scripting interface allows everything from the simplest task to the most complex image manipulation procedures to be easily scripted.

Comment: Gimp has a reputation for not being user-friendly, but I haven't had any trouble with it personally.

Comment: @ klanomath Thankyou for the info...I will give it a try.